# Filtering observations by using grep the reverse way in R

Tags: r, data.table

Shown as below:

```
    df <- data.frame(X1 = rep(letters[1:3],3),
                     X2 = 1:9,
                     X3 = sample(1:50,9))
    df
    ind<- grep("a|c", df$X1)
    library(data.table)
    df_ac <- df[ind,]
    df_b <- df[!ind,]
```

`df_ac` is created using the regular `grep` command. If I want to use the `grep` the reverse way: to select all observations with `X1 == 'b'`. 
I know I can do this by:

```
ind2<- grep("a|c", df$X1, invert = T)
df_b <-df[ind2,]
```

But, in my original script, why does the command `df_b <-df[!ind,]` return a data frame with zero observation? 
Anyone can explain to me why my logic here is wrong? Is there any other way to select observations in a data.frame by using the `grep` reversely without specifying `invert = T`? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `grep` and not `%in%`? Also, you might want to look at `grepl` instead if a `grep` approach is what you want.

Comment: Also, why have you loaded "data.table" here?

Comment: Execute `!ind` in your console and you will see why that expression returns an empty `data.frame`.

Comment: hi, I use "data.table" since my original dataset is huge, I would like to use data.table to manipulate my dataset. I edit my question a little bit. I just want to know why my logic here in `data.table` is not correct. Thank you

Comment: @nrussell Much surprised to me, all `FALSE` by `!ind`. I realize that `grep` returns numerical index, but the `!ind` is a logical operator, which will never give me what I want. I need to use `grepl` instead. Thank you very much for your hint!

Comment: The numerical index works, too, but you need to negate it, like `df[-ind,]`. That works in either a data.frame or a data.table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be more interested in `grepl` instead of `grep`:

```
ind<- grepl("a|c", df$X1)
df[ind,]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  a  1 16
# 3  c  3 38
# 4  a  4 10
# 6  c  6 18
# 7  a  7 33
# 9  c  9 49

df[!ind,]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 2  b  2  5
# 5  b  5 14
# 8  b  8 50
```

---

Alternatively, go ahead an make use of "data.table" and try out `%in%` to see what else might work for you. Notice the difference in the syntax.

```
ind2 <- c("a", "c")
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[X1 %in% ind2]
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1:  a  1 16
# 2:  c  3 38
# 3:  a  4 10
# 4:  c  6 18
# 5:  a  7 33
# 6:  c  9 49

df[!X1 %in% ind2]
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1:  b  2  5
# 2:  b  5 14
# 3:  b  8 50
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works with `grepl`. It seems like `data.table` likes to identify observations using logical patterns rather than using numerical index. I will vote your answer.

Comment: @ChuanTang, You could always do `df[setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df)), ind)]`. But that's much more cumbersome than just using `grepl`.

Comment: @ChuanTang In this case, the logical indexing has benefits, since `%in%` has some optimization. Also, `%chin%` is usually recommended over `%in%` for character vectors (for some reason...).